# Microsoft Multi Tenant App as an Individual Developer - Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to make a multi-tenant application using Microsoft active directory but found out that you need a MPN ID to do so. However, it seems that **you can't sign-up for the Microsoft Partner Network as an Individual Developer** and you instead need to be a registered business. **Is there anyway to create a multi-tenant application as an individual?** I'm assuming something like this must exist akin to how you can publish iOS apps as an individual developer.

Comment: I am currently in the same position. I am even registered as a freelancer in my country, but they‘ve rejected me. I contacted the support asking why I was rejected, I will update my comment when I have more information.

Comment: Hi if my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you:)

Comment: I've called with Microsoft and it seems there is no way to create a multi-tenant app as a individual developer..

Comment: Thank you very much @Fabian! I'm making an enterprise app so having an admin approve my app works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you said "multi-tenant application", it means you need to own an AAD tenant to create it.

I assume that you are already an individual developer registered to Microsoft. What you need to do is [Create a new tenant in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant). Sign into https://portal.azure.com/ with your individual account to do the above operations.

Please note that your account is a personal account currently, you need to follow the the guidance the portal shows (if it shows) to convert it to a work account as well and then you can create the tenant.

After that you can [create multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) in Azure AD.

Select one of the options to make it as multi-tenant app.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

"Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified publishers" alert means normal user cannot do user consent but admin still can do admin consent.

You need to do the admin consent for custom's tenant by using admin consent (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424301/best-practice-for-creating-app-registration-in-customers-tenant?answertab=votes#tab-top)). It doesn't matter that if they don't do the admin consent before using your application. When the first time an admin from other tenant tries to sign into your application, he will be required to do admin consent as well.

Please refer to [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to learn about the authentication process. Using `/common` or `/organization`are both OK.

Comment: I see this option to edit in my already existing azure account. However, whenever I select this, I get a "Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified publishers" alert.

Comment: @lvillacin It means the normal user cannot grant consent. But the admin can grant consent. I have tested it. You can test from your side.

Comment: how will I be implementing this? How will my end users create and account with my app if only the admin can grant consent? Any link to a guide or documentation will definitely help. Thank you very much, I am quite new to using Microsoft Azure overall.

Comment: Needing admins to grant consent to my app is not a problem btw, it is an organization only app so it's fine. However, I do not know how I can implement this. Thank you.

Comment: @lvillacin When an admin of a tenant grant consent for your app, all the users in that tenant will have access to use your app. For how to grant admin consent, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424301/best-practice-for-creating-app-registration-in-customers-tenant?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Comment: thanks! after my app is added to my customer's tenant by the admin, how can users SIgn In with Microsoft to my app? what will be auth endpoint and params? WIll i be sending my users (non admins to /common endpoint or to /organization one? thank you very much.

Comment: @lvillacin Please refer to auth code flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code. Use `/common` or `/organization` are both OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229379/discussion-between-lvillacin-and-allen-wu).