# Best practice for creating app registration in customers tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Looking for best practice for the following scenario.
My application must read user information from Azure AD in many different customers tenants via Microsoft Graph. Is the only way to create an app registration/enterprise app manually in each tenant with the right scope?

Is it possible to create an app registration from admin consent url, or is it only possible from the GUI inside azure portal or via powershell.

Comment: You might find this article useful, to understand how multi-tenant app registrations are defined once (by you, in your tenant), and can be given access (e.g. through consent) by customers in their tenant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use a [multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) and admin consent url.

Create the app registration in your tenant. Assign the Microsoft Graph permissions into it.

Then do the admin consent for customer's tenant using the admin consent endpoint (access the following url in a browser):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of customer}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id of the multi-tenant app}
```

Sign in with the admin account from customer's tenant to do the admin consent. This will added an enterprise app to that tenant.

The enterprise app in customer's tenant will have the permissions you added in your tenant and can call Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Just to clarify. My app must be able to read from graph in the customers tenant. But your solution is applicable in that case also?

Comment: @Gmorken Yes.  My solution works for reading data from customer's Microsoft Graph.

Comment: This only works with delegated permissions right? not application permissions?

Comment: @Gmorken Also works for application permission.

Comment: @Gmorken If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: any other way customer tenant register in azure portal manually